# wait for files to download before creating object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

In my `Session` class I'm creating objects of my `Question` Class. In there I'm downloading images to a local path. Now the issue is that my `LaTeXDoc`class requires that all the images are already saved when being called but however the files are downloaded async, which ofcours has the effect that the files are not present when needed.

**Calls of my classes**

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('session'),function(req, res) {
  var session_file = JSON.parse(fse.readFileSync(req.file.path, 'utf-8'));
  // Session creates the Question objects    
  var session = new Session(session_file);

  var tex = new LaTeXDoc(session); // files should already downloaded here
  ...

  res.sendFile(path.resolve("./tmp/"+tex.pdf_name));
});
```

**Question**

```
const randomstring = require("randomstring");

var http = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

class Question{
    constructor(type, variant, subject, text, possibleAnswers, hint, solution, imageURL){
        ...
        this.imageURL = imageURL
        this.imageName = randomstring.generate()+".png";

        var options = {
            url: this.imageURL,
            dest: './tmp/'+this.imageName
        }

        if (this.imageURL != null){
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(options.dest);
            var request = http.get(options.url, function(response) {
                response.pipe(file);
                console.log(file.path) // => /path/to/dest/image.jpg 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now how do I assure that the files are present when I create my `LaTeXDoc` class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use promises or callbacks in your api if you need to be able to tell when they have finished async actions. This does mean you will need to move asynchronous actions out of your object constructors and into some sort of init method.

ex

```
function init(cb) {
    http.get(options.url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        console.log(file.path) // => /path/to/dest/image.jpg 
        return cb();
    });
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dorward/op-character-map/blob/master/lib/getImages.js might be of use.